# My LED ring is not working when I connect the GND

Tags: microcontroller, led, raspberry-pi

I am working on a small project where I am using a SparkFun Lumini LED Ring. The power supply for the ring is external, connected via its own cable and power adapter. I have connected the ring to the Raspberry Pi using three wires: DI, CI, and GND. The issue is that the ring does not work when GND is connected.  When GND is not connected, the ring does illuminate but not as it should.

The link of the datasheet of the Leds:
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/d/c/a/4/2/APA_102-2020-256-6.pdf

the schematic of Leds:
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/0/4/2/e/a/LuMini_3Inch.pdf

[image: it is the same connection but with a LED-Ring]

it is the same connection but with a LED-Ring

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You need to [edit] your question to include a link to the Lumini datasheet. (You can't assume that we're all familiar with it.) We also need a schematic - the language of electronics - to understand how everything is connected.

Comment: Is the power adapter for the LED ring supplying 5 V?

Comment: yes, it is supplying 5V. The ring works without the GND connection to the raspi but very chaotic and not as it should act.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LED module datasheet says, that the minimum input high level is 0.7 * Vcc. This would be 3.5 V in your setup. So you need some logic level translation from the 3.3 V logic level of the Raspi.

If you disconnect the GND line between Raspi and LED module, the module receives more or less random noise as data. This may destroy the LED inputs or Raspi outputs at any time.

Comment: how can i do this logic level translation? is it possible with a capacitor?

Comment: Capacitive coupling (>=10 uF) in combination with a voltage divider at the LED input side to add an offset voltage sometimes work, but it is just a "quick and dirty hack". An IC like 74AHCT2G125 accepts 3.3 V at the input side and does the translation with a supply of 5 V.

Comment: thank you very much